# Why does my facebook friendlist request doesn't show as many friends as on my profile?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to get my users friends lists by using the facebook graph API doing so:

```
FB.api('me/friends', function(response) {

        console.log(response);
        user.friends = response;

    });
```

When I test on my own profile I get 95% of my fb friends (583 friends instead of the 602 I can see on my profile). Thus, I see in the response object there is a "next" url for the pagination function which doesn't return anything when triggered. Why is this happening ? Where does that possibly come from ?

Thanks

Comment: Hey Miles! Did you find any solution to it? Just curious to know the solution.

Comment: I've asked on the page you linked without any answer ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a problem with *next* URL for the pagination, try using the **offset** and **limit** parameters in the URI.

For example, instead of making an API call to `me/friends`, make a call to `me/friends?limit=100&offset=0`. This will start the list of your friends from an offset of 0 and will display a list of 100 friends on on each page. The next URL will work just fine in this case. You can however increase the limit of the users per page.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way of getting all the friends in a single call ?

Comment: Yes, you can retrieve all at once by increasing the limit (Max allowed is 5000). But, the problem with Facebook API is that it is not able to all the friends. Have a look at [this](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/). I think this is the reason why some of the users are missing from you retrieved list.

Comment: thanks but I don't get what you mean by " the problem with Facebook API is that it is not able to all the friends" can you clarify please ? :)

Comment: I would have clarified it to you at first place if I'd known what the actual problem is. I tried looking for it for a while, but didn't get anything. The link that I attached in my previous post says that FB "removes results not visible to viewers", that's it. Nothing about it anywhere else. It's actually quite surprising that having spend such a huge amount of money every year on API, there still are some bugs in the API.
Anyways, you can some research on it, if you want. Do post it here in case you find an answer to it. :)

Comment: What's weirdest still is that the next page URL can be missing, even if there are more results... I can hardly see a technical justification for this, other than not caring. And this makes it quite awkward to fully reliably get all the items in a dataset.